# docker swarm - can't connect to service

Tags: azure, docker, nginx, docker-swarm

I wanted to learn docker swarm but I can't get it working on a fresh azure instance with debian 10.1 (edit: I also tried debian 9.11)

I've isolated the problem only to the following commands, which should give me a simple nginx welcome page on port 9000:

```
docker swarm init
docker service create --name nginx -p 9000:80 nginx
curl -vvv localhost:9000
```

But actually curl hangs and the service does not respond:

```
* Expire in 1 ms for 1 (transfer 0x5574dbd88f50)
* Expire in 1 ms for 1 (transfer 0x5574dbd88f50)
* Expire in 1 ms for 1 (transfer 0x5574dbd88f50)
*   Trying ::1...
* TCP_NODELAY set
* Expire in 149998 ms for 3 (transfer 0x5574dbd88f50)
* Expire in 200 ms for 4 (transfer 0x5574dbd88f50)
* Connected to localhost (::1) port 9000 (#0)
> GET / HTTP/1.1
> Host: localhost:9000
> User-Agent: curl/7.64.0
> Accept: */*
>
```

Running nginx with `docker run` on the machine works.

Running the above commands on my windows machine with docker also works.

But as soon as I'm using `docker stack deploy` or `docker service create` I can't connect to the exposed ports.

Has this something to do with debian? My setup? Did I missed some configuration? What can I do to investigate this problem?

Docker version is 19.03.4

Comment: please share the run commands that succeeds

Comment: @rok: a simple `docker run -d -p 9000:80 nginx`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It may be that curl is using IPv6 and Nginx isn't configured for it.  Try:

`curl -vvv 127.0.0.1:9000`

Comment: Thank you very very much! You were right. Can you explain why curl is able to connect to the port and then hangs?

Comment: No problem.  Think of the exposed port as a proxy server.  If the proxy server is running, you can connect to it, regardless of whether the server you're trying to get to is reachable.

Answer (score 0):

Use the command `docker service ls` to list the services. There you will find a column with the state of your service. If it is listed, then proceed to know if there is any error. Use the command `docker service ps nginx` and check the column `Current state`. If everything is healthy then check nginx logs with the command `docker service logs -f nginx`. Show us that, and we can continue helping.

Comment: State is 'running' with no errors. The log for nginx is empty for both containers. Before I ran portainer and the log output for `docker run` and `docker stack deploy` was exactly the same.

Answer (score 0):

I ran into a similar problem with curl hanging for docker swarm. I initially thought it was an issue with `traefik`, however I could reproduce it with a simple `httpd` container also. So it is probably related to ipv6 being selected by curl. Here are some options that worked

1. Adding `-4` option to curl to force `ipv4`. This helped, but was intermittent.
2. Adding `net.ipv6.conf.all.disable_ipv6 = 1` and `net.ipv6.conf.default.disable_ipv6 = 1` to `sudo vi /etc/sysctl.conf` file and reloading it via `sudo sysctl -p`. Again intermittent.
3. Creating an overlay network `docker network create -d overlay dcm-net` and in the `docker-compose.yml` file marking this network external as follows:

```
networks:
  dcm-net:
    external: true
```

Option 3 worked the best for now.